# How do I dynamically create dependency implementations as they are referenced in Spring?

Tags: spring

The situation here is that I have an interface that has dynamic implementations.  These implementations need to be instantiated at runtime and used by injecting the interface:

```
public interface Configuration {
    void doStuff();
}

public interface ExampleConfiguration extends Configuration {
    void doStuff();
}
```

ExampleConfiguration has an implementation generated dynamically. I.e, there is no ExampleConfigurationImpl class.  This is proving difficult to integrate into Spring because I want to have these generated implementations injected automatically:

```
@Autowired
private ExampleConfiguration config;
```

I went down the road of adding a BeanPostProcessor but it looks like unresolved dependencies don't go through there (as I would expect).

Essentially, is there a way to contribute a factory that will be called (with contextual information such as a DependencyDescriptor instance) in an attempt to resolve a missing dependency?  There will be multiple interfaces extending the Configuration interface.

Spring version is 3.0.3.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a [`FactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html)?

```
public class ExampleConfigurationFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<ExampleConfiguration> {
    @Override
    public ExampleConfiguration getObject() throws Exception {
        return //...magic here
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return ExampleConfiguration.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I don't know how you actually create these dynamic beans (I suspect some dynamic proxy being involved), but insert your logic in *magic here* placeholder. Should work. You use the `FactoryBean` as if it had a target type in your XML:

```
<bean id="exampleConfigurationFactoryBean" class="ExampleConfigurationFactoryBean"/>
<bean id="someBean">
    <!-- exampleConfiguration is of ExampleConfiguration type -->
    <property name="exampleConfiguration" ref="exampleConfigurationFactoryBean"/>
</bean>
```

Spring will call `getObject()` when requested.

Comment: +1/2 - Can you show the XML required in `applicationContext.xml` to setup and reference the factory bean?

Comment: So I did go down the factory bean approach but the problem is that there are multiple cases of interfaces that extend Configuration.  I would need a factory bean for every extension of Configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've got some way to actually manufacture the instances? Well, all you need to do is to make that factory into a bean itself and add the right annotations:

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class ConfigBean {
    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
    public ExampleConfiguration getObject() throws Exception {
        return //...magic here
    }
}
```

You use the usual Spring techniques for hooking to any configuration you need. (I assume you're using `<context:component-scan>` and `<context:annotation-config>`…)

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that i would need to create a new method for every implementation of the base interface.